# How to change a GLOBAL Node's value with VisM?

Tags: vb.net, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I have access with VisM via VB.net, and can query GLOBAL nodes with it.
However, let's say I have a node that looks like this,

```
^KOT("CNTR","KOT")  =   38499
```

how can I chage the value `38499` to something else? like an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to do, just set new value to P0, and execute COS command SET this value to the global

```
AxVisM1.P0 = "newvalue"
AxVisM1.Execute("set ^KOT("CNTR","KOT")=P0")
```

Comment: what would we do without you :)

Comment: It was too easy ;) Ask your tough questions here: community.intersystems.com

Comment: DAiMor, since I asked about editing.. how about if we decide to add another global node?

Comment: You can do it in exactly the same way, for such set command when global reference on a left side does not matter it is has any value before or not.